# jQuery visible selector returns wrong length

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out when all forms of a certain class are hidden. I have the following:

```
$('.fix').submit( function(event) {
    ...
    $.ajax({
         ...
         success: function(data) {
                ...
                $(this).slideToggle(checkIfDoneCorrecting());
            }
    });
});
function checkIfDoneCorrecting() {
    console.log( $('.fix:visible').length );
    if( ! $('.fix:visible').length ) {
        console.log('none visible');
        $("#grade").slideToggle();
    }
}
```

There are originally 3 visible forms. After the first $.ajax is run, the submitted form is hidden, so there are 2 visible forms. However on the console it prints out 3. Then on the next one, it prints out 2 when there is only 1 form visible. Since I am calling the function after the element is hidden, why is it not getting the updated visible count?

Comment: @c0deNinja um, it is right there in the code...

Comment: `$(this).slideToggle(checkIfDoneCorrecting());` ... on slide toggles callback

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything preventing that form from actually submitting ?

Comment: @gta0004 Are you cancelling the form submission in the submit? or did you chop that out in the ...?

Comment: @user3649503 What? That's irrelevant, my question is not about the form, it is about the visible selector.

Comment: @epascarello yes, the form submission is fine.

Comment: Just a side note, i think it would be a lot easier for you to use if($('.fix').is(':visible'))..

Comment: @gta0004: The `checkIfDoneCorrecting` is not invoked as a callback. You're invoking it immediately before the `.slideToggle` runs. It should be this: `$(this).slideToggle(checkIfDoneCorrecting);` Not this: `$(this).slideToggle(checkIfDoneCorrecting());`

Comment: Well, the visible selector works, so you obviously have more visible elements than you think, you just have to figure out why.

Comment: @cookiemonster - gee, good eyes spotting those parenthesis, that's probably it.

Comment: @cookiemonster Oh nice, that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The .slideToggle() method animates the height of the matched elements.
>   This causes lower parts of the page to slide up or down, appearing to
>   reveal or conceal the items. If the element is initially displayed, it
>   will be hidden; if hidden, it will be shown.

In slideToggle() there will be animation and that means there is delay. But you are invoking the callback function to check length asap.

So it's giving you wrong length as it's not hidden.

The proper callback will be

```
$(this).slideToggle(checkIfDoneCorrecting);

// without the paranthesis
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in  `slideToggle` , and the function will be called after the animation  is completed.

```
$('.fix').submit( function(event) {
    $(this).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
    checkIfDoneCorrecting();
    });
});

function checkIfDoneCorrecting() {
    console.log( $('.fix:visible').length );
}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a6je5/).